# Download Ubuntu 11.10 with all update and upgrade

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, updates, cd

Where can I get Ubuntu 11.10 with all update till now? Because every time i have update to Internet and it take hour for that.

Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

Easy answer - you don't. The LTS LiveCD is updated once every half-year, and the normal versions are made once and then left that way unless something very extraordinary shows up.

Intermediate answer - By installing from the MinimalCD (quite a lot more advanced than using the LiveCD, but it should give you the latest) you'll get the latest when installing. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: Ofc you can make your own LiveCD with the latest updates, but that's probably overkill since that will set you back quite a few hours ;)

Comment: It looks like the minimal CD requires even more downloading on install -- the opposite of what OP is looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Every time I download a image, it takes at least 15 to 20 minutes. Depending on bandwidth it may take hours. I am not endorsing piracy (I have got warnings before in other places entioning torrents of linux) you can get torrents somewhere that may go faster. The seeders are what give the speed. As far as I know every copy of Ubuntu comes up to date. You will still have to update wireless and flash... ect. I am not a expert, but thaty is my 2 cents ... lol.

Comment: Like when the ubuntu 11.10 released the kernel version was 3.0.0.12 and now i think it is 3.0.0.15

Comment: Downloading a free operating system with any protocol, including torrents, does not constitute piracy.